# How can I set an Azure Devops pipeline variable via an inline PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have an Azure Devops build YAML file that contains the following task:

```js
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Set coverage variable'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=coverage]Get-Content .\coverage\lcov-report\summary.txt"
```

I would like this task to set the variable `coverage` to be the value of the contents of `summary.txt`. However, when accessing the variable in the following task, I see that the variable is literally the string `Get-Content .\coverage\lcov-report\summary.txt`.

There seems to be no example anywhere in the documentation as to how to pull this off. Is it just a limitation of scripting? Do I have to set the `Get-Content` command to a variable and then access that variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use $() after ].

Example:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=coverage]$(Get-Content .\coverage\lcov-report\summary.txt)"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's documented. But may be not too obvious in our official doc :) You could find related doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#set-variables-in-pipeline):

> *Important*
>
> **Predefined variables that contain file paths are translated to the appropriate styling** (Windows style C:\foo\ versus Unix style /foo/)
>   based on agent host type and shell type. If you are running bash
>   script tasks on Windows, you should **use the environment variable
>   method for accessing these variables rather than the pipeline variable
>   method** to ensure you have the correct file path styling.

Since you are using is pipeline variable, the value returned by `'Get-Content .\coverage\lcov-report\summary.txt'` as a string type, it's an expected behavior.

However $() accepts a variable not a string. Use `$(Get-Content .\coverage\lcov-report\summary.txt)`

After this, in the following task, simple use below to read the value.

```
Write-Host No problem reading $env:coverage
```

Comment: Oh I see! I think there was just a mismatch in semantics for what was in my mind vs on the page. When I read that `$()` accepts a variable, I was imagining `$(coverage)` being what was required. I treated the `$(Get-Content ...)` as an expression instead of a variable